# AsyncTask not generic?

Tags: android, generics, android-asynctask

When I try to compile to following code, I get two errors:

Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error on token "void", invalid Expression `AsyncTask.java /AsyncTask Project/src/org/me/asynctask` line 19 Java Problem

Description Resource Path Location Type
The type `AsyncTask` is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<TextView, Void, Void> AsyncTask.java /AsyncTask Project/src/org/me/asynctask` line 25 Java Problem

```
package org.me.asynctask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.*;
public class AsyncTask extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView mytextview = new TextView(this);
        TextView secondtextview = new TextView(this);

        new MyAsyncClass().execute(mytextview, void, secondtextview);
    }

    private class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, Void> {
    protected TextView doInBackground(TextView tv)
    {
        tv.setText("Your AsyncTask was successful!");
        return tv;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(TextView Result)
    {
        Context context = context.getApplicationContext();
        Toast mytoast = Toast.makeText(context, "AsyncTask processing complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        mytoast.show();
    }
}
```

Obviously `AsyncTask` IS a generic (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)  so why do I get those errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems, two of which are:

1. You defined a class `AsyncTask`, which hides/collides with `android.os.AsyncTask`. Maybe you intended to call it AsyncTaskDemo.java or AsyncTaskActivity.java or something.
2. You're trying to change the UI from the background thread by calling `tv.setText` inside of `doInBackground`. That defeats the purpose of `AsyncTask`. Code in `doInBackground` shouldn't be touching the main (or 'UI') thread. For mid-task updates inside of `doInBackground`, use `AsyncTask.publishProgress`.

Answer (score 5):

You are overriding the AsyncTask methods with the wrong types.  It is defined as:

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

and the doInBackground method is defined as 
    protected abstract Result  doInBackground  (Params... params)

so according to your definition, you should have
   protected Void doInBackround(TextView... params);

onPostExecute is also incorrectly defined.